# Create new array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with the next structure:

```
$collection = array (
    array('category' => 'buildings',
          'id' => 9),
    array('category' => 'buildings',
          'id' => 8),
    array('category' => 'trees',
          'id' => 11),
    array('category' => 'trees',
          'id' => 12),
    array('category' => 'trees',
          'id' => 11),
)
```

I need to create next collection:

```
array ('buildings' => array (9, 8),
       'trees' => array (10, 12, 11),
)
```

So I use for it foreach () and array_push(). First of all if new collection hasn't current category. If not, I set empty array, push id to it. But if category exists in new collection I push id value to array ans add to collection. So my code is:

```
function getCategoriesAndTypes($collection)
{
    $categoriesAndTypes = [];
    $typesCollection = [];
    foreach ($collection as $object) {
    $category = $object['category'];

    if (! array_key_exists($category, $categoriesAndTypes)) {
        $typesCollection = [];
        array_push($typesCollection, $object['type']);
        $categoriesAndTypes[$category] = $typesCollection;
    } else {
        array_push($typesCollection, $object['type']);
        $categoriesAndTypes[$category] = $typesCollection;
    }

}

return $categoriesAndTypes;
}
```

But I think that more pretty sollutions exist! Can you help me to refactor my code? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored my code to next variant:

```
function getCategoriesAndTypesFromLibraryFolder($collection)
{
    $categoriesAndTypes = [];
    $typesCollection = [];

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        if (! array_key_exists($object['category'], $categoriesAndTypes)) {
            $typesCollection = [];
        }

        array_push($typesCollection, $object['type']);
        $categoriesAndTypes[$object['category']] = $typesCollection;
    }

    return $categoriesAndTypes;
}
```

Have you idea to make it better?

Comment: Yes, correct it so it works.... $object['type'] does not exist... it is meant to be $object['id'] which you will know as you would have got the same error I did when you ran it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following method would be enough:

```
function getCategoriesAndTypesFromLibraryFolder($collection)
{
    $categoriesAndTypes = [];

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $categoriesAndTypes[$item['category']][] = $item['id'];
    }

    return $categoriesAndTypes;
}
```

The result is:

```
array ( 'buildings' => array ( 0 => 9, 1 => 8, ), 
        'trees' => array ( 0 => 11, 1 => 12, 2 => 11, ), )
```